How to Enable Restrict User Networking in virt-manager QEMU/KVM User Session?
I want to isolate my network between host and guest in QEMU User Session (qemu:///session). block the unnecessary guest to host and guest to guest networking.
I found an article on QEMU wiki talks about Networking, and it mentioned an option called restricted, it can be used to isolate network, but I cannot found the option in virt-manager.
Anyone knows how to enable it in virt-manager or any other solution available for isolating networks between Host and Guest in QEMU user session?

It's possible with non default virtual switch (ex. openvswitch) + creating custom nftables ruleset to control networking. but it's a lot of work, it would take a very long post here to guide you trough. the default networking in virtmanager is one big problem because it auto creates IPTABLES rules that allow networking and you have no control over this.
